# Find center of gravity of a group of boxes in a suspended structure

Tags: javascript, math, gravity

[image]

I want to know if it's possible show a user which red dot to assign the blue circumference in order to maintain the centre of gravity of the suspended structure.

Each box has a certain angle in both of its suspending cables defined by the user.
He can assign as many boxes as he wishes.

I thought of JavaScript to make the calculus, it doesn't have to be graphic at all, the red dots have its number. The resulting of the calculus that had the most proximate result should be the choice.

I haven't found any examples that could do this, only math formulas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't a programming question 

Answer (score 2):

Formulas ought be enough, as long as you understand them.  Just three mass-weighted coordinates:

```
xbar = sum(M(i)*x(i))/sum(M(i))
ybar = sum(M(i)*y(i))/sum(M(i))
zbar = sum(M(i)*z(i))/sum(M(i))
```

The (x, y, z) are the centroids of the individual boxes, which are easy to calculate.

I would not expect to find your precise scenario in code anywhere.  You'll wait a long time for that.

Comment: That's exactly right I don't have proper knowledge, that's why I'm having difficulties.

An example of a JavaScript that can rotate boxes in user input would be a huge help. My greatest difficulty is finding a «context» in wich that code belongs all together..